# Why this code is working for 1 and 2 yet fails for input that is more than 3?

Tags: c, nested-loops

So I am trying to print patterns in C.

```
For n = 2
Output:
2 2 2
2 1 2
2 2 2
for n = 3
Output:
3 3 3 3 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 3 3 3 3 
and so on.
```

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int nn = n;
    int *arr;
    arr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    int f = 0; //flag to check if I reached the mid of the pattern
    int l = 2*n-1; //Lenght of square to be generated
    int temp1 = 0;
    int temp2 = l;
    for(int i = 0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(int j = temp1;j<temp2;j++) //change values in range temp1 to temp2
        {
            arr[j] = n;
        }
        for(int k = 0;k<l;k++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        if(n == 1)
        {
            f = 1;
        }
        if(f==0)        //For upper half of pattern
        {
            n=n-1;
            temp1=temp1+1;
            temp2=temp2-1;
        }
        else if(f==1) //For lower half of pattern
        {
            n=n+1;
            temp1=temp1-1;
            temp2=temp2+1;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I am getting the correct output for n = 2 but when I am inputting anything above 2 the code is crashing.
I am not able to find what should be done. Can someone help me out and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you find which line triggers the crash? What are the values of the variables appearing in that line?

Comment: First of all, have you tried to solve it using pen and paper? Then have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values (and to make sure your code does what it's supposed to do and that it follows what you came up with using pen and paper)?

Comment: A hint though: How many elements do you allocate for `arr`? And how many elements of that array do you actually use (for example in the loop `for(int j = temp1;j<temp2;j++)`)?

Comment: First have a look to your memory allocation you need (n+1)*(n+1) places.

Comment: @JaMiT It shows that igoe.exe has stopped working.Returns 255<0xFF>

Comment: @NoobKing "It"? What is this "it" of which you speak? Probably not a debugger, which would be an appropriate tool for this situation. (If you are unable to use a debugger, diagnostic messages sent to `std::cerr` can go a long way towards locating the crash point.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Got it the array size allocation was wrong.It should be 2*n-1.Thank you

Comment: @JaMiT yes its not a debugger I'll use debugger from now on it was a logical error where I allocated less space for the array. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to check distances by axis and take a maximum of them to be printed.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int vertical_distance;
    int horizontal_distance;
    
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n * 2 + 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n * 2 + 1; j++)
        {
            vertical_distance   = abs(n - i);
            horizontal_distance = abs(n - j);
            if (vertical_distance > horizontal_distance)
                printf("%d ", vertical_distance);
            else
                printf("%d ", horizontal_distance);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Also, when I ran your code it worked nicely with large numbers (3, 7, 15).
I just pasted your code to onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler and ran it. Can you please add the error message that you have got?

(sry for my English)

Comment: The array size allocation was wrong so the program just crashed like the .exe file has stopped working. This is a more elegant solution.Thank you. PS: Your English is fine.

Answer (score 1):

in this code piece

```c
for(int j = temp1;j<temp2;j++) //change values in range temp1 to temp2
{
      arr[j] = n;
}
```

j can be bigger than n. but arr malloc space is n. the array overflowed.

it will work with a small change

```
arr = (int*)malloc(2*n*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that Out! Actually works with  (2*n-1).